# npx typeorm migration:create -n TestData Dosen't create a migration

Tags: typeorm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA9Bu.png)

I wasn't able to create a migration even after following doc.

Comment: The answer is in your screenshot. By the way: don't post screenshots.

Comment: Doc's doesn't cover any sort of arguments parsing `typeorm migration:create -n PostRefactoring` and If I have to parse an argument what should it be?

Comment: _"Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1"_. Also, I don't see `-n` being mentioned as a valid argument. Consider that the documentation, or the version you have installed, may be outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the update *(I don't know which, exactly)*, the flag `-n` was replaced by `-o`.

So, **now you need to run**.

> `typeorm migration:create -o path/to/my/migration`

### If you are using multiple datasources

**`migration:create`** doesn't work with specific datasources, so
I reccomend you to add two scripts in `"scripts"` session at `package.json` like the following:

**default typeorm (that you will use for non-specific database stuff):**

`"typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"`

**your custom typeorm (that you will use for your specific database stuff, like run & revert migrations):**

`"myTypeorm":"ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -d path/to/my/ormconfig.ts"`